# ImageView inside item in listview change's randomly

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I'm trying to do a custom listview with a favorite option, the thing is that when I add some items to favorite and then scroll down the fav button change order randomly, **the other thing that I need** help with is that I don't know how to change a favorite imageview when other is clicked (Because You can only have 1 favorite option)

This is my custom adapter

```
public class LineasAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
protected List<Lineas> lineas;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public LineasAdapter(Context context, List<Lineas> lista){
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.lineas = lista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lineas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lineas.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista,
                parent, false);

        holder.numero = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.number);
        holder.titulo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        holder.subtitulo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.subtitulo);
        holder.star = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.star);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



    Lineas linea = lineas.get(position);
    holder.numero.setText(linea.numero_s());
    holder.titulo.setText(linea.titulo());
    holder.subtitulo.setText(linea.subtitulo());

    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = convertView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("Favorito",0).edit();
    final int numero = linea.numero();
    final Context c = convertView.getContext();
    final ImageView estrella = holder.star;
/** this is where I change my fav button and add the number to some sharedpreferences **/
    holder.star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editor.putInt("linea", numero );
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(c,"Has agregado a favoritos a el cole numero "+String.valueOf(numero), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            estrella.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView numero;
    TextView titulo;
    TextView subtitulo;
    ImageView star;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace getview method with follwing ...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista,parent, false);

    holder.numero = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
    holder.titulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
    holder.subtitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo);
    holder.star = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.star);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

Lineas linea = lineas.get(position);
holder.numero.setText(linea.numero_s());
holder.titulo.setText(linea.titulo());
holder.subtitulo.setText(linea.subtitulo());

final SharedPreferences.Editor editor =          convertView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("Favorito",0).edit();
final int numero = linea.numero();
final Context c = convertView.getContext();
final ImageView estrella = holder.star;
/** this is where I change my fav button and add the number to some sharedpreferences **/
holder.star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editor.putInt("linea", numero );
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(c,"Has agregado a favoritos a el cole numero "+String.valueOf(numero),                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        estrella.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
    }
});

return convertView;
```

}